# Как дождаться асинхронной функции ?(javascript)

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```js
arr = [7, 2, 8, 4, 3];
arr2 = [];
arr.forEach(async function(item, i) {
  var z = await func(item);
  // операции над z
  arr2.push(z);
});

arr2.forEach(function(item, i) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

Проблема в том, что 2й цикл с `arr2` начинает работу до того, как закончит первый цикл, а `arr2.push(z)` до того, как `z` получит результат.

Как исправить ?

Answer (score 4):

Если хочется параллельно запустить несколько асинхронных функций и дождаться их результата, то лучше использовать [Promise.all](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#promise-all-iterable) и [arr.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). `forEach` здесь никак не подходит.

Пример кода, Который демонстрирует эту идею:

```
arr = [7, 2, 8, 4, 3];
Promise.all(arr.map(async function(item, i) {
  var z = await func(item);
  // операции над z
  return z;
})).then(arr2 => {
  arr2.forEach(function(item, i) {
    console.log(item);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

И откуда эта мода на forEach().
Правильно будет вот так.

```
( async () => {
  const arr = [7, 2, 8, 4, 3];
  const arr2 = new Array ( arr.length );
  for ( const [index,item] of arr.entries() ){
     const z = await func(item);
     // операции над z
     arr2[index] = z;
  }
  for ( const item of arr2 ){
    console.log ( item );
  }
} )()
```

Вот так всё выполняется в нужной последовательности.

Толково. Наглядно. И даже комментарии не нужны.